# Callkit Call Back button not working

Tags: ios, iphone, callkit

I have an app that is integrated with callkit and after a call has been rejected or a call fails the native callkit ui pops up and shows a call back button however when pressed the performStartCallAction callback never gets triggered. There seem to be people who have posted the same problem but there doesn't seem to be a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding `performStartCallAction:`. The only way that that method can get called is if your app created a `CXStartCallAction` object and then called `requestTransaction:` on a `CXCallController` to request a transaction with this action. Only your app can initiate a start call by explicitly requesting it; nothing outside your app can do it.

When the user tries to "make a call" through your app from outside the app, for example by pressing a past call in Recents in the Phone app, or pressing call to a contact in the Contacts app, by pressing the "video" button in an audio call, or (I presume) doing "Call Back", the way that your app is notified of this is by being sent an `INStartAudioCallIntent` or `INStartVideoCallIntent` in your app delegate's `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` method. How your app handles this is entirely up to you; it can do nothing, it can initiate a new CallKit call (to the same or a different contact), or it can do something else in your app's interface; whatever you want.